# How to build clickable URL from UrlName returned from a SOSL query for KnowledgeArticleVersion

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component that runs SOSL to find a list of articles and uses aura:iteration to display them. Now I need the list to display a link to the knowledge article that is visible in our public community. So I have a static URL to our community that just needs to append the UrlName returned from apex. 
Some thing like

```
<a href="http://*URLtoCommunity*" + {!v.kav.UrlName}>View Article</a>
```

Any ideas how to do this in lightning?

Here is a link to a previous question that has all the code for my component. [How to use comparable interface to sort a list?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117854/how-to-use-comparable-interface-to-sort-a-list)

Comment: did you try <a href="http://*URLtoCommunity*" + {!articles.kav.UrlName}>View Article</a> ? I used "articles" as per your link for reference.

Comment: how about ; href="http://*URLtoCommunity* & {!articles.kav.UrlName}"

Comment: Little different error: ParseError at [row,col]:[13,170] Message: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.: Source

Comment: When I try to use the entity name for ampersand (&amp;): Failed to save undefined: Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}: Source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right syntax is as below for lightning components

```
<a href="{!'http://*URLtoCommunity*/'+articles.kav.UrlName}">
```

Answer (score 0):

From your prev ques link;

```
<aura:iteration var="articles" items="{!v.articles}">
        <p>Article ID: {!articles.kav.Id} | Article Title: {!articles.kav.Title} | Article Type: {!articles.kav.ArticleType} |  <a href="http://*URLtoCommunity*" + {!articles.kav.UrlName}>View Article</a></aura:iteration>
```

href="http://*URLtoCommunity* & {!articles.kav.UrlName}"

Comment: I did try this. I get this error: ParseError at [row,col]:[13,170] Message: Element type "a" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".: Source. Looks like the a href must be escaped before trying to use expression syntax.